# How to get the product of all combinations of values by column?

Tags: r

for example, if I have a matrix as following

```
> matrix(c(1, 1:8), nrow = 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    6
[2,]    1    4    7
[3,]    2    5    8
```

then how to get a vector of the product of all combinations of values by column (listed below)?

please note that 1 has repeated twice

```
1 * 3 * 6
1 * 3 * 7
1 * 3 * 8

1 * 4 * 6
1 * 4 * 7
1 * 4 * 8

1 * 5 * 6
1 * 5 * 7
1 * 5 * 8

1 * 3 * 6
1 * 3 * 7
1 * 3 * 8

1 * 4 * 6
1 * 4 * 7
1 * 4 * 8

1 * 5 * 6
1 * 5 * 7
1 * 5 * 8

2 * 3 * 6
2 * 3 * 7
2 * 3 * 8

2 * 4 * 6
2 * 4 * 7
2 * 4 * 8

2 * 5 * 6
2 * 5 * 7
2 * 5 * 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to a `data.frame`, do an `expand.grid` on the columns and then `Reduce` by multiplying each row

```
Reduce(`*`, expand.grid(as.data.frame(m1)))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
expand_grid(V1 = m1[,1], V2 = m1[,2], V3 = m1[, 3]) %>%
     transmute(out = reduce(., `*`)) %>%
     pull(out)
#[1] 18 21 24 24 28 32 30 35 40 18 21 24 24 28 32 30 35 40 36 42 48 48 56 64 60 70 80
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(m1)[, Reduce(`*`, do.call(CJ, .SD))]
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1, 1:8), nrow = 3)
```